# Django and elasticbeanstalk: Collectstatic always fails once on the admin css

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've installed my Django app on AWS through elasticbeanstalk to give it a shot, and I can't say it's as simple as Heroku (I almost went back to manually configuring my EC2 instance) but now things are working.

One thing is annoying though, I always have to run "eb deploy" twice because the first one always fails on an widget.css file from the admin

```
[13:39]: (master) eb deploy                                                       
Creating application version archive "bc5f".
Uploading mycitypack/bc5f.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
INFO: Environment update is starting.
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).
INFO: Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Info. Command is executing on all instances.
ERROR: [Instance: i-slk438sd0] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...thon2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 120, in collect
raise processed
ValueError: The file 'admin/css/widgets.css' could not be found with <core.custom_storages.StaticStorage object at 0x7f3sx85av2d0>.
container_command 02_collectstatic in .ebextensions/02_options.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-ad4cxa86q2'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.

[13:40]: (master) eb deploy                                                       
WARNING: Deploying a previously deployed commit.
INFO: Environment update is starting.
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).
WARN: Environment health has transitioned from Info to Degraded. Command failed on all instances.
INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
INFO: Environment update completed successfully.
```

Not sure to understand what's up there... 
My options.config is simply doing collectstatic and migrations:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrateall:
    command: "python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "core.settings.prod"
    PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/mycitypack:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "core/wsgi.py"
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
```

Eb logs:

```
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
  Post-processed 'admin/img/sorting-icons.gif' as 'admin/img/sorting-icons.2a27f8855e6b.gif'
  Post-processed 'admin/img/icon-unknown.gif' as 'admin/img/icon-unknown.662022bb6ab0.gif'
  Post-processed 'admin/img/icon-yes.gif' as 'admin/img/icon-yes.0596085e212f.gif'
  Post-processed 'admin/img/icon_error.gif' as 'admin/img/icon_error.d0272cd88394.gif'
  Post-processed 'admin/img/tooltag-arrowright.png' as 'admin/img/tooltag-arrowright.5aa2c86314d7.png'
  Post-processed 'admin/img/inline-delete-8bit.png' as 'admin/img/inline-delete-8bit.1c135ffae5f0.png'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
  Post-processed 'admin/img/sorting-icons.gif' as 'admin/img/sorting-icons.2a27f8855e6b.gif'
  Post-processed 'admin/img/icon-unknown.gif' as 'admin/img/icon-unknown.662022bb6ab0.gif'
  Post-processed 'admin/img/icon-yes.gif' as 'admin/img/icon-yes.0596085e212f.gif'
  Post-processed 'admin/img/icon_error.gif' as 'admin/img/icon_error.d0272cd88394.gif'
  Post-processed 'admin/img/tooltag-arrowright.png' as 'admin/img/tooltag-arrowright.5aa2c86314d7.png
'
  Post-processed 'admin/img/inline-delete-8bit.png' as 'admin/img/inline-delete-8bit.1c135ffae5f0.png
'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", l
ine 338, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", l
ine 330, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 168, in handle
  collected = self.collect()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/collectfast/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 68, in collect
  ret = super(Command, self).collect()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 120, in collect
  raise processed
  ValueError: The file 'admin/css/widgets.css' could not be found with <core.custom_storages.StaticStorage object at 0x7f3ab85af2d0>.
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)


[2015-10-22T11:39:57.663Z] ERROR [31305] : Command CMD-AppDeploy failed!
[2015-10-22T11:39:57.663Z] INFO  [31305] : Command processor returning results:
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"(TRUNCATED)...thon2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py\", line 120, in collect\  ret = super(Command, self).collect()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/
commands/collectstatic.py", line 120, in collect
  raise processed
  ValueError: The file 'admin/css/widgets.css' could not be found with <core.custom_storages.StaticSt
orage object at 0x7f3ab85af2d0>.
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)


[2015-10-22T11:39:57.663Z] ERROR [31305] : Command CMD-AppDeploy failed!
[2015-10-22T11:39:57.663Z] INFO  [31305] : Command processor returning results:
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"(TRUNCATED)...thon2.7/s
ite-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py\", line 120, in collect\
nraise processed\nValueError: The file 'admin/css/widgets.css' could not be found with <core.custom_storages.StaticStorage object at 0x7f3ab85af2d0>. \ncontainer_command 02_collectstatic in .ebextensions/02_options.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI","returncode":1,"events":[]}],"truncated":"true"}
```

Not sure if it comes from a Django config problem or beanstalk itself?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try on a bigger instance?

Comment: I'm kind of stuck on the dev instance for now, I'll check if memory pressure can cause collectstatic to fail (weird that it would always fail at the same file though)

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? I have a similar config which results in "Page Not Found" whenever I deploy. If I remove the `collectstatic` part, the site works but is missing the styles.